# Limit fields in MongoDB response

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am doing a join using `$lookup`, but I'm getting all the field, including those which are not required, so i need to restrict it.

Here is my query

```
exports.query = function (req, res) {
    QuestionList.aggregate([{
                $match : {
                    topicName : req.query.topicName
                }
            }, {
                $lookup : {
                    from : "questions",
                    localField : "quesList.quesListName",
                    foreignField : "quesListName",
                    as : "quesListCount"
                }
            }
        ], {
        quesList : 0
    }, function (err, questionList) {
        console.log(questionList);
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(fnData(questionList));
    });
};
```

the response I am getting is

```
{
    _id : "57453e45a11c97483f97a4c9",
    quesList : {
        by : "swathi",
        quesListName : "Controller Question List",
        quesListCount : [{
                quesListName : "Controller Question List",
                question : "What is a Controller function?"
            }
        ]
    },

}
```

here I need to restrict `quesListName` in `quesListCount` array .

Comment: What did you try so far? It is quite well documented https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-specific-fields-from-embedded-documents

Comment: are you going to get count only from joined collection? please post `questions` schema

Comment: var QuestionsSchema = new Schema({
    topicName: String,
    quesListName: String,
    question:String

});